# Why do I get 400 bad request in Edge browser only, with fetch?

Tags: wordpress, fetch, microsoft-edge, http-status-code-400

I am developing a Wordpress plugin and in admin settings (only) I get bad request 400 when using fetch API but only in Edge browser. Why could this be? I cleared the cookies, but it didn't help.

I would paste more code, but it would be irrelevant since it works perfectly on every other browser, but Edge.

I'm getting `HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax` in console. Nothing in request seems to be bad. I rewrote the same request to use POST instead of get, but result is the same.

Comment: Without the code how could we test it in Edge?

Answer (score 2):

From inception Edge appears to have bee out of sync with other browser implementations for fetch (even missing some native methods).

Issues: 24 Aug 2018 "[Fetch Api post not working in latest version of edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18775440/)"  (not fixed). I'm not sure if this has the same root as your issue. One contributor solved problem for them by ensuring body is string e.g.

```
body: urlParams({
  username: this.state.username,
  password: this.state.password,
  _csrf: token
}).toString()
```

A report of [400 fetch issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11358518/) in 2016  was referred on to [an issue identifying another Edge feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/599)  "*It looks like we put LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (U+200E) around punctuation marks, but Chrome and Firefox don't.*"

In Edge dev tools (F12) check console log for JS errors; and under Network check what you are actually sending to your server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting `HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax` in console. Nothing in request seems to be bad. I rewrote the same request to use POST instead of get, but result is the same. So the GET request doesn't use body at all as far as I understand..

Comment: 1: If actual status 400 then by implication your server got the request. I guess you should be able to see exactly what Edge sent via Dev Tools - Network - select appropriate request then click "Header" etc and maybe find content causing error. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11358518/#comment-2 . I don't think I can add any more as my experience is limited to use of jquery Ajax.

Comment: 2: Note. There is an occasional intermittent glitch (at least on my PC) with Edge; I can submit a URL (even for a simple page) and Dev Tools Network sometimes fails to list/record any of the resulting requests (even for simple pages).

Comment: Can you try to provide a sample code or a detailed steps to reproduce the issue on our side? Then We can try to make a test. With only this error, it is not possible for us to find the root cause for the issue as this error can be occur due to various reasons. You can also try to make a test using other machine with MS Edge to check whether you get similar error or not. It can help to narrow down the issue.